# "They have lived here for 10 years"

Tags: grammar, tense

What does this sentence tell about their current situation?are they still living here or is it obscure?

Answer (score 1):

They still live there. The Present Perfect tense tells me about it. Compare:

> They have lived here for 10 years (they still do).
>
> They lived here for 10 years (they live somewhere else now).

Comment: Then what's the difference between this and "they have been living here".

Comment: Difference between " they have lived here for 10 years"and "they have been living here for 10 years".

Comment: @ManishKumarBalayan "they've been living here for 10 years" is about them living here now, just like "they've lived here for 10 years" is. They are pretty much the same.

Comment: There has to be some difference.i suppose

Comment: @ManishKumarBalayan there is but it's slight (at least in this context). Using the present perfect continuous, we emphasize the duration of the action. The present perfect emphasizes the action.